# Picture Preview with input type "file" that works in all versions of IE (8 and up), using WebMatrix (C#) and/or JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, image, webmatrix

How can I get Picture Previews to work with IE 8 and up?

Can I get binary image data from an input type "file", with JavaScript/jQuery?

If I can just get the data (in the right format) back to the server, I should be able to work with it there, and then return it with AJAX (although, I am absolutely no AJAX expert).

There is, according to the research that I have done, NO WAY to get picture previews in all IE versions using only javascript (this is because getting the full file path is seen, by them, as a potential security risk). I could ask my users to add the site to the trusted sites, but you don't usually ask users to tamper with those kinds of low-level settings (not to mention the quickest way to make your site seem suspicious to users is to ask them to directly add your site to the trusted sites list. That's like sending an email and asking for a password. "Just trust me! I'm soooo safe!" :)

I have picture previews working in everything except IE and have no problem using conditional comments to separate an IE specific way of doing this from the way I am doing it with other browsers.  In other words, the answer doesn't even have to be cross-browser, just cross-IE (8 and 9).  I know I have seen IE sites use picture previews before (somehow), so I know there must be at least ONE way to do this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you need to support IE lower than 10 you could upload the file to the server using some of the existing AJAX upload components (Uploadify, Plupload, Valums AJAX Upload, Bleuimp, ...), generate and store a thumbnail on the server and send the url to the saved image to the client using JSON so that it could display it using an  tag. Actually since IE supports Data URI Scheme you don't need to store the uploaded file to the server in order to generate the preview. You could directly return the resulting thumbnail image from your Preview controller action formatted as Data URI Scheme so that you could show it on the client.

Another solution if you don't have the time and resources to implement this functionality is to simply tell your users that if they want to get a realtime preview of the image that they should consider using a different web browser because your site doesn't support IE for this.